# Can i update ubuntu while i currently have themes

Tags: 16.04, updates, 18.04

I have some themes installed on ubuntu 16.04 right now and im running plank as well, i wanted to know if i could safely just update to 18 right now or would i have to restore defaults and uninstall any extra features

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a little more information, is your /home folder on a partition that won't be formatted? What do you mean by theme, gnome theme?

I assume this is the case. I use [Vertex theme](https://github.com/horst3180/vertex-theme) for my system. I updated from 17.10 to 18.04 today (I've had the same home partition since 14.04) and this worked just fine. This is what I did:

- Installed Ubuntu `/` over my old partition and chose to mount my existing `/home` as usual
- Once installed I ran the instructions for my theme described in the github link above
- Then I rebooted, without making any changes to theme or system settings.

Once it booted again my themes were automatically selected and active. I don't use plank however, but I assume if you install it and don't change any settings then it will come back as it was after a reboot, so long as you don't add new favourites to your unity bar or make too many system changes.

Comment: Ah, im running a mac theme for unity with custom icons so i was wondering if it would create any issues. I didnt separate the partitions

Comment: Ah so you are running an upgrade rather than a fresh install. I wouldn't recommend this option as it is largely untested compared with installing things fresh. That said it "should" be ok to do without losing your files, though you will probably have to re-select themes to restore them.

Comment: As a side note, applications tend to have a `.skype` folder in your home drive(or whatever the app name is). Use CTRL+H to reveal hidden folders. You could backup the configs to the apps you want to keep on a usb stick just in case. These can live in multiple places, like `.local` so look up each app you want to backup and find it's corresponding files.